# Wit.ai chooses wrong branch in conversation flow

Tags: wit.ai

I have a flow based conversation modelled in wit.ai. After executing a custom action and sending the results to the user, the user should have the possibility to:

- say something like 'show me more' or
- say something like 'thank you' in which case the flow is configured to return a direct message 'you are welcome'

I used two separate intents 'more' and 'thank you' to differentiate between the branches. When I send 'show me more' to the bot, wit.ai correctly recognizes the intent 'more'. However, the conversation then takes the wrong branch and the bot sends 'you are welcome' as shown in this wit.ai response body:

```
{
  "confidence" : 1,
  "type" : "msg",
  "msg" : "You are welcome!",
  "entities" : {
    "intent" : [ {
      "confidence" : 0.9707855789235582,
      "type" : "value",
      "value" : "more"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Am having a similar issue. Say I have two intents, "hello" and "thank you". I've configured my stories with "bot sends" "hi" and "you're welcome", respectively. Somehow, the bot recognizes the "thank you" intent, but responds with "hi".

Comment: Could you copy&paste the conversation flow? I'm doing something semi-identical and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Well even I have faced similar issue sometimes but I was able to get it working by setting the right context or entity field names for "has" & "does not have" options for respective actions and responses in the Actions tab. This seems to have worked although it is a bit frustrating to see that Wit does not recognise the flow based on intent sometimes.